# Maximizing the product of projections of a vector on another vectors

Tags: complex-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, nonlinear-optimization

I want to get the $N\times1$ complex vector $\mathbf{x}$ which maximizes this real valued function

$f=\mathbf{x}^{H}\left (\mathbf{a}_{1} \mathbf{a}_{1}^{H}\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^{H}\mathbf{a}_{2} \mathbf{a}_{2}^{H} \right )\mathbf{x}$,             subject to $||\mathbf{x}||=1$

where $\mathbf{a}_{1}$and $\mathbf{a}_{2}$ are $N\times1$ known complex vectors, and
$(.)^{H}$ is the complex conjugate operator

Can any one help by closed form solution or an iterative algorithm?

Comment: Could we just write this as $\bf (x\cdot a_1)^2(x\cdot a_2)^2$?

Answer (score 0):

You may write this as
$$|\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{a}_1|^2|\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{a}_2|^2=|(\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{a}_1)(\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{a}_2)|^2$$
Minima and maxima of the parenthesized thing at the right side will be maxima of the squared version. We are thus looking to minimize

$$(\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{a}_1)(\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{a}_2)=\vec{x}A\vec{x}$$
where $A_{ij}=a_{1i}a_{2j}^\ast$ is a generalized projection matrix.

Findng a minimum of
$$\vec{x}A\vec{x}-\lambda |x|^2$$
where $\lambda$ is a Lagrange multiplier to ensure unit length of $\vec{x}$, you arrive at the eigenvalue problem
$$A\vec{x}=\lambda \vec{x}$$

Because you are maximizing the product of projections to two axes, the solution will naturally be a superposition of these two axes (any rotation out of this plane minimizes both projections).

$$\mathbf{x}=X_1\mathbf{a}_1+X_2 \mathbf{a}_2$$

This reduces this problem to a $2\times 2$ eigenvalue problem.

Comment: Only, we are considering the complex case, and this complicates things because Lagrange multipliers does not lead to the eigenvalue problem, in this case.

Comment: Thanks Orion and Omran Kouba. The superposition of the vectors is the best solution for real valued vectors but for the complex case it is not the best. I used the superposition solution as an initial solution and performed MATLAB optimization function "fmincon" and "interior point algorithm" and it gives a solution with larger value for the objective function $f$. I want to know if I can use an iterative algorithm to reach the global solution from the superposition solution as an initial one?